# Fetch all data from feathers-vuex

Tags: vuex, feathersjs

I store a couple thousands google maps markers in an API done with feathersjs. I use feathers-vuex on the frontend and I need to fetch all this data on created(). This is what I have so far, but it only fetches 10 items.

```
<script>
    import { mapState, mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex'

    export default {
        name: 'a-map',
        computed: {
            ...mapGetters('plates', {
                plates: 'list'
            })
        },
        methods: {
            ...mapActions('plates', {
                findPlates: 'find'
            })
        },
        created() {
            // Query plates from Feathers
            this.findPlates();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a good explanation in the docs of feathers-Vuex. Look here:

[hhttps://vuex.feathersjs.com/common-patterns.html#reactive-lists-with-live-queries](https://vuex.feathersjs.com/common-patterns.html#reactive-lists-with-live-queries)

The issue is you have to read records from backend into Feather-vuex-store in created. With the getter in computed you get records from the feathers-Vuex store. The benefit of this is computed is synchronized with the backend, even if somebody add, mutate or delete records in the backend.

Comment: Sadly, this link no longer works :( Do you have an update?

Answer (score 0):

You have pagination on your service which  means (by default) only the first 10 items will show. You can either delete the pagination setting on your service, update it, or take advantage of the pagination by using `$skip` in subsequent requests.

[Pagination documentation](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/databases/common.html#pagination)

Answer (score -1):

WMDTech is right, this is because of pagination in your backend. A simple fix is to do the following, but be wary of large datasets

Give this a try:

```
    created() {
        // Query plates from Feathers
        this.findPlates( {
            paginate: false
        });
    }
```

Comment: `paginate` is not sent from the client to the server, that only works in the backend. This is the only answer: https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers/issues/382#issuecomment-238407741

Comment: :O aaaaaaaaaaaa